# Injecting a new object VS injecting existing object when using Dependency Injection?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

1. When using dependency injection how does a class user understands when constructor requires a new instance of an object and when not?

For example, class `Car` requires a new instance of a class implementing `IEngine` interface.

```
public class Car
    public sub new(Engine as IEngine)
    end sub
end class
```

Meanwhile, class `Messager` doesn't require a new instance of a class implementing `ILogger` interface.

```
public class Messager
    public sub new(Logger as ILogger)
    end sub
end class
```

2. How can a developer or a user minimize risk of misuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using dependency injection how does a class user understands when
>   constructor requires a new instance of an object and when not?

If the class requires a new instances of its dependency, you are breaking the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), because you are leaking implementation details into the consuming class. This class should not know and should not care about this.

At runtime you might construct a special engine type that can't be reused, but it's up to the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) to know about this; the consumer should not care.

Perhaps the problem you are having is caused by injecting objects with runtime data into services. With dependency injection you build object graphs of components (classes with behavior) and you pass through data objects (such as messages, DTOs, entities, etc) this object graph through method calls. Anytime you break this rule by injecting state (i.e. runtime data) into a component's constructor, you will find yourself in trouble.

A common source of bugs however is a problem called [Captive Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). A captive dependency is a dependency that is configured to have a shorter lifetime than its consuming type. For instance your `Car` could be registered as singleton, while `IEngine` is a transient. The `Car` will in that case keep the `IEngine` alive for much longer than intended.

There are a few ways to prevent this.

For instance, when building object graphs by hand, you'll often find that these errors pop up quite easily; but unfortunately not always.

In case you use a DI library, some libraries (Simple Injector and Castle Windsor) contain diagnostic tools that warn you about such mistake.

Another good way to prevent this is to prevent your components from keeping any state. This allows you to make this complete object graph consist of singletons, and this will prevent getting into this problem in the first place. This doesn't mean that you can't have objects (such as an unit of work) that have a shorter lifestyle, but you only have to prevent those objects from being injected into the constructors of components in your object graph.

Comment: You are right! I was injecting data objects in constructors! Never thought it was wrong.